# Solve limit of rational function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, limits, rational-functions

I have function:
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow -2}\frac{x^3+3x^2+2x}{x^2-x-6}$$
after calculations I got:
$$\frac{-8+12-4}{4+2-6} = \frac{0}{0}$$
What must I do from here? I have tried to divide by (x-1), but I guess this is wrong. Can you post all steps to answer with explanation. Thank you

Comment: Divide by what creates zero, it is $x-(-2)=x+2$.

Comment: To be more precise, divide numerator and denominator by $x+2$ to get an expression which is equivalent to the given one for $x\ne -2$

Comment: Just to explain a little more, if you have a polynomial $p(x)$, polynomial division gives $p(x)=(x-r)q(x)+c$ for any value of $r$ you care to choose (the constant $c$ depends on $r$ of course). Then setting $x=r$ on either side gives $p(r)=c$ so that $p(x)=(x-r)q(x)+p(r)$. Now, if you know that $p(r)=0$ you definitely have $c=0$ and you can tell that $x-r$ is a factor of the original polynomial. So the people who are helping you with answers know that $x+2$ will be a factor of numerator and denominator from this simple observation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\require{cancel}x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x = x(x^2 + 3x + 2) = x(x+1)(x+2)$. Also, $x^2-x-6 = (x-3)(x+2)$, so

$$\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow -2}\frac{x^3+3x^2+2x}{x^2-x-6} & = \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x(x+1)(x+2)}{(x-3)(x+2)} \\
& = \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x(x+1)\cancel{(x+2)}}{(x-3)\cancel{(x+2)}} \\
&= \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x(x+1)}{(x-3)} \\
&= \frac{-2\times-1}{-2-3} \\
&= -\frac{2}{5}
\end{align}$$

Comment: How you get values from second step?

Comment: From factorising the polynomials $x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x$ and $x^2 - x - 6$, then cancelling.

Comment: I do not understand. Please include it as steps

Comment: Can you show me solution with divide numerator and denominator by x+2

Comment: That's exactly what's going on here

Comment: I don't understand how $$x^2−x−6$$ is equeals to $$(x−3)(x+2)$$

Comment: $(x-3)(x+2) = x(x+2) - 3(x+2) = x^2 + 2x - 3x - 6 = x^2 - x - 6$

Comment: Is there an easy way to transform those $$x(x^2 + 3x + 2) = x(x+1)(x+2)$$

Answer (score 2):

L'Hopital's rule states that if $f(n)=g(n)=0$, then
$$\lim_{x \to n}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x \to n}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
So your limit is the same as
$$\lim_{x \to -2}\frac{3x^2+6x+2}{2x-1}$$
Which is
$$\frac{3(-2)^2+6(-2)+2}{2(-2)-1}$$
$$\frac{12-12+2}{-4-1}$$
$$-\frac{2}{5}$$

Comment: How you get values from second step?

Comment: I took the derivatives of the polynomials on the top and bottom of the original rational function.

Comment: Can you include that as steps

Comment: Can you show me solution with divide numerator and denominator by x+2

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the fraction first by factoring and canceling the $(x+2)$ term.
$$ \begin{align*}
 &\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{(x+2)(x+1)x}{(x+2)(x-3)} \\
 &= \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{(x+1)x}{x-3}  \\
 &= \frac{(-1)(-2)}{-5}  \\
&= \frac{-2}{5} 
\end{align*} $$

Comment: Can you show me solution with divide numerator and denominator by x+2

Answer (score 0):

Use the L'Hôpital rule: as you have the indetermination 0/0, derive the functions from the numerator and denominator until your limit has a solution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Answer (score 0):

Let us simplify the function

$$f (x)=x\frac {x^2-x-6+4x+8}{x^2-x-6} $$
$$=x (1+4\frac {x+2}{(x+2)(x-3)}) $$
$$=x (1+4\frac {1}{x-3} )$$

the limit is
$$-2 (1-\frac {4}{5})=-\frac {2}{5} $$

Comment: Can you show me solution with divide numerator and denominator by x+2?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The factorization of the numerator and denominator is elementary as you know one of their roots ($-2$), and the numerator has no independent term.

Then

$$\frac{x^3+3x^2+2x}{x^2-x-6}=\frac{x(x+1)(x+2)}{(x-3)(x+2)}=\frac{x(x+1)}{x-3}$$

for all $x\ne-2$.

Comment: I do not understand. Can you please elaborate

Comment: What precisely don't you understand ?

Comment: An easy way to get $$\frac{x(x+1)(x+2)}{(x-3)(x+2)}$$

Comment: Puling out $x$ is obvious. Then for the quadratic polynomials you can use the standard root formulas. But as you know one of the roots, the Vieta formulas easily give you the other.

Comment: You can also consider a tentative factorization $(x+2)(x+a)=x^2+(2+a)x+2a$ and compare to the given coefficients.